# Fresh Ubuntu Install Being Extremely Slow

Tags: 16.04

Ubuntu has become a bit of a nightmare for me.

I have a brand new desktop (i3-8100 – 8th gen, Ripjaws V 16gb DDR4, Z370 Aorus Gaming 5 chipset, 2x 4TB hard drives + 1x 1TB hard drive). I had installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and everything was working perfectly.

Randomly about a month ago I couldn't log in. I'd get stuck on the login screen. I tried to debug but no success, so I thought forget it I'll format and create a fresh install. Ubuntu loads up and it's slow to the point of being unusable. Typing the word terminal takes 10 seconds. If I want to move a window it is super laggy. Again, please keep in mind everything was perfect a month ago and this machine is new.

It's a fresh install, so no processes or anything else. This has been a nightmare, would really appreciate some help.

#### Output from `systemd-analyze blame`

On my first attempt about 2-3 minutes in:
Bootup is not yet finished. Please try again later.

On my second attempt:

```
8min 19.825s apt-daily-upgrade.service
1min 58.770s apt-daily.service
1min 11.176s systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-4479ee04\x2df118\x2d4da6\x2d99ef\x2d2735ef7460e0.service
      8.118s dev-sdb2.device
      7.252s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      5.868s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
      5.397s systemd-sysctl.service
      2.024s keyboard-setup.service
      1.891s ModemManager.service
      1.868s accounts-daemon.service
      1.836s grub-common.service
      1.783s NetworkManager.service
      1.578s lightdm.service
      1.551s upower.service
      1.450s thermald.service
      1.036s systemd-journald.service
       895ms polkitd.service
       854ms systemd-modules-load.service
       781ms systemd-rfkill.service
       748ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
       748ms dev-mqueue.mount
       745ms dev-hugepages.mount
       510ms irqbalance.service
       411ms kmod-static-nodes.service
       275ms console-setup.service
       259ms ufw.service
       249ms apparmor.service
       242ms networking.service
       235ms avahi-daemon.service
       204ms ondemand.service
       204ms home.mount
       196ms rsyslog.service
       195ms gpu-manager.service
       194ms pppd-dns.service
       141ms udisks2.service
       126ms plymouth-start.service
       124ms dev-sdb1.swap
       124ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
       117ms wpa_supplicant.service
       110ms systemd-update-utmp.service
        93ms systemd-udevd.service
        66ms systemd-journal-flush.service
        64ms user@1000.service
        57ms setvtrgb.service
        37ms colord.service
        36ms systemd-random-seed.service
        32ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
        30ms systemd-remount-fs.service
        28ms plymouth-read-write.service
        23ms systemd-timesyncd.service
        23ms systemd-logind.service
        21ms speech-dispatcher.service
        14ms apport.service
        12ms bluetooth.service
        10ms alsa-restore.service
         8ms snapd.autoimport.service
         5ms systemd-user-sessions.service
         3ms dns-clean.service
         3ms plymouth-quit-wait.service
         2ms rtkit-daemon.service
         2ms ureadahead-stop.service
         2ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
         1ms resolvconf.service
         1ms rc-local.service
         1ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
       352us snapd.socket
```

Comment: What is it doing slowly?  Is boot slow, or is doing other particular things slow?

Comment: If it is slow booting, run `systemd-analyze blame` from the terminal. Copy the output and paste it into your question.

Comment: One of the disks beginning to fail?

Comment: @thomasrutter typing the word terminal takes 10 seconds. If I want to move a window it is super laggy. Also updated my answer to include this. Again, please just keep in mind everything was perfect a month ago and this machine is new. Thanks.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix thanks, I didn't know about this command. I've updated my question above.

Comment: I'm on my phone so can't link one but there are various articles on speeding up `systemd` boot and I'm pretty sure apt daily can be relocated.

Comment: The dev/disk is a concern too.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I didn't know what "systemd-analyze blame" does but I learnt it prints a list of all running units which can help optimize boot-up times. So before I go down that road, (1) Should we not assume that if I waited 10-30 minutes that the system would then be perfectly fast? Since it does not speed up I doubt it's the boot. Or am I missing something? (2) Why would I need to optimize the boot if it was working find before, and still works fine booting off a thumb drive? It makes no sense to me why everything was fine and is fine when loading the OS off a thumbdrive.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution but I'm not satisfied with the answer.

The ONLY difference between the nearly 10 unsuccessful Ubuntu installs I had and the one that did work was this:
[ubuntu install options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOBaA.png)

I went back and re-installed with these options for "Encrypt..." and "Use LVM..." checked and now everything works fine. Can someone explain why this impacts system performance? I'd really like to understand.

Comment: Encryption and Logical Volume Management sound like using a sledge hammer on a thumb tack. But if it works you might as well keep it that way. Just remember to backup your documents. In two days time sign back on and accept your answer as the solution so others know it works now.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I definitely will. Still curious to see if people have an answer as to why this worked though. I hate doing stuff without knowing why :P